# Sufficient conditions for refactoring

Tags: design, project-management, refactoring

I've found that many codebases in large companies degrade over time, only adding new features and never improving the design of the codebase. Gradually, these codebases degrade to what is considered "that legacy system no one wants to work on".

However, I do know that one *can* refactor a code base: "improving design without changing its behavior” (Michael C. Feathers, 2005, p. 5)

My question is: what conditions are sufficient for successful refactoring? What differentiates a codebase that *can* be refactored from one that cannot be feasibly refactored?

Comment: Legacy code is code without tests. If you have plenty of code coverage, you are quite safe in refactoring as you see fit without breaking anything by following the test results. If you don't have test you first need to write them, and writing tests is boring and hard especially for a code base not written with testing it in mind

Comment: Its not always wise to refactor, all refactoring introduces risk sometimes with only a moderate often unused rewards.   You have to be extremely strategic with what you choose or not choose to refactor.  There's no one size fits all rule.  Usually I create a greenspace within a nasty app to work from.

Comment: "Legacy code is code without tests" - Hardly... I know plenty of non-legacy code that isn't well tested and plenty of legacy code that's covered in tests

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I do agree with you on the technicality. But, I have seen Bakuriu's definition in the past, actually in the same book as I refenced in my question: "working effectively with legacy code". But MY interpretation of that statement is to not take it literally, but rather as: "code without tests, should be treated as legacy code" Because with no tests you are less sure of its behaviour and making changes becomes a challenge.

Comment: I’ve seen horrible code bases that had a lot of tests. You start refactoring, all the tests break while no relevant bug has been catched. If testing was the magic bullet we wouldn’t have so much crappy software.

Comment: Tests _should_ provide understanding of behavior. Legacy code, I suppose you could then say, is code with poor understanding of behavior - especially subtle behaviors. Automated tests _can_ provide that understanding, but they can also be useless, or worse. However, without tests, where do you get that understanding? Good documentation can help, but then making that documentation _testable_ is even better, because documentation rots faster than code.

Comment: @DirkBoer I think you could assume that when someone says "tests" they mean "useful tests". It's fair that some tests are not useful, but of course those aren't what is important. It's the tests that are useful that matter. (And some languages have mutation testing that can tell you if your tests are useful, at least in catching errors)

Comment: @ScottishTapWater "Legacy code is code without tests" is the definition of "legacy code" that Michael C. Feathers introduced at the beginning of its book "working effectively with legacy code". It stress the fact that the age of the code base is far less important than a good test coverage

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi who died and made Michael C the king of legacy code? Yes, he wrote a decent enough book but that doesn't mean he gets to redefine a term for the whole industry

Comment: @ScottishTapWater I don't think anyone here thinks that Michael Feathers gets to decide for the whole industry. I think people mention that definition, because it implies some specific things that are useful to consider. For example that code without tests are harder to refactor, and should be approached a different way.

Comment: Legacy code is any code that has been deployed. Once it's out, and it has to be supported, it's legacy code.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Refactoring takes time. If not done well, it creates bugs that you need to fix. So it costs. You refactor when the benefits outweigh the cost of refactoring.

There are good times for refactoring: one time is immediately after the code is written. At that time:

- you know the code
- you know exactly what it is supposed to do
- you know how to improve it
- there hasn't been enough time to remove bugs due to maturing of the software, so bugs added during refactoring are not a big deal

Another time is when you need to change the code's behaviour and the code is in such bad shape that making changes is hard and risky, and so it is more effective to first refactor and put the code into good shape and *then* make the behaviour changes.

NOT a good time is when you look at the code and don't like it, and that's your only reason to change the code.

(And please look at the other answers describing how to refactor successfully. Important are: having tests that find when you introduce bugs, and finding available tools to help you.)

Comment: On the other hand, if look at the code and don't _understand_ it, then spend hours/days working through it to understand it... then it may be a good time to refactor it for clarity so the next developer to come along doesn't lose as much time as you did.

Comment: If not understanding it is the only reason, then no. If you lose time looking at it, then don’t look at it. Maybe in a year or two the code isn’t needed anymore, so every second you spent is lost.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I would say code that you "don't understand" is not a refactor problem but a documentation problem. If I take code that you don't understand, add in 20 high-quality test cases and sample usage, it is unlikely to stay a mystery for long. Hard to understand code is mainly lack of documentation. Truly difficult to understand code would be esoteric stuff, but those are actually quite easy to recognize.

Comment: Part of the question is: Why are you trying to understand the code? Probably because you plan to change the code's behavior, you are trying to test the code, or you are trying to document the code. If you are just trying to understand it for some other reason then no, don't refactor. This answer covers the case where the code is so bad that making changes is hard. But what if you want to better document/test the code (but not yet change behavior) and that is prohibitively difficult? Is that cause for refactoring?

Comment: Actually reading some other answers and reflecting on the importance of testing for refactoring, the real kicker question is: Say you have a hard-to-understand but important legacy codebase with no or limited testing. Should you refactor in this case? refactoring is risky because testing is poor, but writing tests is challenging because the code is hard to understand. Should you go through and write tests and refactor as you go? Or try to go through, understand the code, write tests, and then refactor only if you want to change behavior?

Comment: @Jagerber48: You should definitely always write your tests first, then refactor. Not only when the code is difficult to understand, but also when you _think_ that you understand it ;-) When you have hard-to-understand code it's a good strategy to get test data from a production system. That gives you inputs and expected outputs that you can use for some black box tests. Then refactor the hell out of the code, re-run the tests and be surprised by the results. It's incredible how much you can learn this way!

Comment: @gnasher729: I was thinking of a debugging situation. Where the application behaves in an unexpected way -- often dubbed a "bug", though sometimes it may actually be intended by its authors -- then you first have to understand the code (and the reasons for it) prior to even deciding whether there's anything to fix. In case of particular poor code, I consider this a good occasion for a clean-up. Or any other words: tackling technical debt. It's not unusual for requirements to have changed since the code creation, and for simplification to be possible.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Only if you're making changes, *and* you think it's likely that more people will need to make further changes in future.

Comment: _"NOT a good time is when you look at the code and don’t like it"_ I reckon that depends on the current level of technical debt and the scope/blast radius of what you're looking to change. In a relatively clean-practice codebase and for a small-scope change, "drive-by fixing" is a very strong approach to keeping technical debt at bay. However, this does require self-discipline as to picking the right battles and limiting the size of your battles. It's not foolproof by any means, but it is in my opinion one of the best ways of continually suppressing the growth of any technical debt.

Comment: @Treb many times I thought I understood the code I had just written. I'd quickly write a some tests covering obvious cases and find out that the code didn't behave as I expected in some of those. I some times do this for code reviews, as well. Somebody has written some code and I can't figure it out by reading. I'd create some tests for what I expect and see what it does. Then if it fails, submit those to the author. Some times it turns out my expectation was wrong, but other times the author just forgot to consider something. Tests are useful in clarifying what something does.

Comment: "There are good times for refactoring: One is immediately after the code is written." - Very much this.  So much so that you should plan for it.  As in, first just write code that solves the problem you're trying to solve.  Don't even worry about trying to write "good", well-structured code; just solve the problem and verify that you've solved it.  Then after the solution is confirmed, take a look at what you've done, think about what would be the best way to structure it, and refactor it accordingly.

Comment: @aroth, my understanding of "refactoring" as a word, has always been that it inherently excludes the initial development process. Certainly, development often involves first drafts of code which sketch out the basic concepts, the basic steps, or solve sub-problems or special areas of difficulty, which are then put in a much tidier form or reinforced with auxiliary functionality. But I've always considered this to be the process of factoring the code in the first place, not a "refactoring".

Answer (score 26):

To enable a codebase to be refactored, the fundamental necessity is test coverage. Ideally fast, automated test coverage. You want to be able to assert, with high confidence after every refactoring step, that you have not introduced a behavioral change. You get that confidence and make those assertions with test coverage. When you're refactoring, you're changing the internal structure, so your unit tests will also need to be refactored. However, your higher-level tests should remain stable. If you don't have robust testing or if your code isn't easily testable, [characterization tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) are a good way to get some test coverage to enable refactoring.

But, in my experience, most of the barriers to refactoring aren't technical. Being allowed and encouraged to spend time to improving the readability, maintainability, and testability of the codebase isn't often seen as a good investment of time. Instead, there's an ongoing drive for delivering new features for customers. However, investing in refactoring - especially if the codebase is high in technical debt - can make it faster and safer to deliver these new features and reduce the likelihood of defects in those new features.

Comment: The necessity is to be able to reliably & controllably achieve equivalence of behavior. This requires some combination of careful analysis and testing. Automated testing is good, but robust analysis can (if needed) shoulder a fair amount of weight. I generally prefer equivalence as a first step, but divergence can be allowable where it is due to bugs being fixed. All divergence however must be rigorously accounted for.

Comment: @ThomasW Not only do I disagree that analysis is sufficient, people like Michael Feathers (author of [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052) and an early proponent, if not creator, of characterization testing) and Martin Fowler (author of [Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html)) don't agree either. Automated testing is much more efficient and effective than human analysis.

Comment: I generally don't trust human analysis on the plain fact that managers can pressure them to deliver results that they want. You aren't going to pressure automated tests to give you a pass unless you screw around with it, but that's not going to fool anyone.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I find that is highly contingent on what facilities exist for automatic testing. I mostly write in SQL these days, and it can be practically impossible to programmatically test the workings of database engines, especially for defects which occur only under certain circumstances of concurrent load. Manual analysis is often all you have.

Comment: @Steve Concurrent load shouldn't cause behavioral changes. Refactoring - and the tests to support it - are about the functional behavior. And depending on your database, there are unit test frameworks for your SQL statements. I find it unlikely that there are no frameworks or harnesses to allow you to write automated tests for your SQL queries or prepared statements.

Comment: I strongly agree with this, with the understanding that you don't just mean unit tests.  If that's correct, I think it would be good to clarify that in the answer.  Unit tests are helpful for refactoring inside a very narrow scope only.

Comment: @JimmyJames Do you have suggestions for improvement? The last 3 sentences of the first paragraph should make it clear that unit tests are likely to be more fragile in refactoring so you need higher level integration and system tests.

Comment: I'm blanking on a good wording, but it might come to me when I stop thinking actively about it.  I think some people may see 'automated' and 'test coverage' (especially) and incorrectly assume you mean 'unit tests', if that helps.

Comment: @JimmyJames Thanks. I'll think it through. But if anything comes to you, feel free to drop an edit or a comment and maybe that'll help me. I definitely don't mean to point people to "unit test".

Comment: @ThomasOwens, unfortunately concurrent loads do cause behaviour changes in databases, but more importantly certain kinds of "functional" defect can only be revealed under concurrent load (and often in very specific patterns or under very specific timing constraints). Some things are easily testable of course, but those who don't routinely work with databases can be surprised about the size of the space where manual analysis is the only practicable form of testing, and therefore has to be a sufficient form of testing.

Comment: @Steve I'm confused. Are you talking about _implementing a database engine_ or _testing database queries that are part of an application_? It's not uncommon to mock a database engine for most unit tests, and even some integration tests. These types of defects would only be exposed during a narrow subset of system level tests running at production loads in a production-like environment. I think that's beyond the scope of this question, which is about refactoring your code.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I'm talking about testing queries that are part of a database application. The OP asked under what conditions can refactoring occur, you responded "test coverage; ideally automated; manual analysis is not sufficient". It's in that context that I'm emphasising that almost all database work lacks automated test coverage (especially coverage of interactions between concurrent processes, which could be altered by any kind of refactoring). (1/2)

Comment: Database application development relies heavily on manual analysis, by those who have the global understanding of the application's processes necessary to identify and analyse such interactions. The loss of those who have the global understanding is almost certainly fatal to the ability to make further significant changes safely. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Then I disagree. If it's in the application, there's no reason it can't be covered by unit, integration, and system level automated tests. If it happens to be in stored procedures, depending on your database technology, there may be ways to implement test coverage. If your queries and procedures lack test coverage, you should implement that before refactoring.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I'm using "application" in the broad sense to include the database that sits at the core of most important business applications. You talk very casually about implementing test coverage for queries and stored procedures, and that causes me to suspect that you don't understand what actually needs to be covered by those tests in order for the coverage to be full - because if you did, you'd already know that there are no conventional facilities to implement those tests, and therefore you wouldn't be implicitly urging people to embark on something that is practically impossible.

Comment: @Steve What you are saying makes absolutely no sense. I've written plenty of tests, including at a system level, that set up data in a database, run tests and verify the behavior of the system (including at production data scale and production user load), and clear the database. If you are suggesting that the tests should exercise the database itself, testing the implementation details of a third-party dependency is widely considered a bad practice.

Comment: What a commotion over testing!  I would definitely require testing of refactorings, often a combination of automation and manual testing. But I would expect a logically robust manual analysis as a necessary first step.. and generally wouldn'tsupport refactoring done without clear analysis. A high degree of confidence from independent sources is needed for any but small changes. My experience in this area is numerous successful refactorings, from modest to transformative, in very large & sensitive codebases. Your & other practitioners mileage may vary of course.

Comment: Database testing. Most application database interactions should be testable with a kind of tests which are technically _integration tests_ but could be called "database unit tests". These test small or modest application actions, using both object model & database. Rollback and a combination of test dataset & data creation fixtures can be to effectively make tests independent and reliable.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I'm sure you've written plenty of tests against databases. The question is whether you're *fully covering* all the relevant things, which would allow you to safely refactor on the strength of the automatic tests alone. I'm not suggesting testing the built-in functionality of the database itself - I'm talking about testing of the database application, the behaviour of the code and configuration that is particular to a bespoke development which uses a database engine. (1/3)

Comment: To give you just one example, very small changes can cause two algorithms to deadlock when executed concurrently - including parts of the algorithm that an SQL-based engine controls automatically, and aren't usually specified by the programmer. Sometimes, just changing the timing of execution can cause such deadlocks where none previously manifest - no change to the algorithm, just the timing. Do you write automatic tests which exercise every possible concurrent schedule of execution of every possible combination of algorithm in your database, to find these deadlocks pre-emptively? (2/3)

Comment: No, you don't. And because you aren't covering testing for the existence of deadlocks, you're probably not testing (by any automatic means) whether the code you've written handles deadlocks correctly either, including what happens if retries don't work, or how your wider business procedures will cope under these circumstances where the computer cannot make normal progress under normal time constraints. (3/3)

Comment: @Steve I still disagree, and I doubt you'll be able to change my mind. Keep in mind that I never said anything about "full coverage". I talk about _enough coverage_ to "assert, with high confidence" that your code changes do not introduce behavioral changes. Unless you're writing a critical system, the kind of exhaustive testing that you're talking about is not usually necessary to achieve high confidence. In most business systems, reasonable timeouts, alerting of timeouts with diagnostic information, and retry is sufficient, and that behavior can be tested to assert functional correctness.

Comment: @ThomasOwens, I agree with you that such automatic testing is not necessary, because it isn't worthwhile relative to the effort and the lack of facility for it. In its place stands manual analysis of correctness, with effort targeted in a risk-based fashion based on manual analysis of the risks and likely interactions. I'm only picking at this point because the overall gist of your remarks seems to be that automatic tests are not only best, but that they are also practicable, and so refactoring can safely proceed whenever there is evidence of substantial automatic testing in place. (1/2)

Comment: I encourage more caution than this, whenever the application in question is a database application, which often have extremely delicate designs. If automatic tests exist at all, they are unlikely to fully cover important failure modes, and therefore any refactoring requires review and manual re-analysis by a capable member of staff. Certain failures will also not necessarily be detectable like deadlocks (which was only an example) - refactoring changes may interact with hidden assumptions (or existing unrevealed defects) in concurrency behaviour, to cause subtle data damage. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve This is going to be my last comment. Tests are the best tool to support refactoring, and tests should be automated when possible. The team may do additional analysis, but refactoring without tests, and ideally automated tests, is dangerous. Words like "substantial" and "full coverage" are your words and your words alone - I have never used such phrasing. The amount of test coverage depends on the criticality of your system and the risk tolerance of the stakeholders, and it is up to the team to decide how much is necessary to ensure safe refactoring.

Answer (score 6):

A significant factor is tooling used by the team and the proficiency with which developers use the tools. The concept of refactoring was originally developed in the Smalltalk context, and there were a number of tools developed to support this activity:

- a Refactoring browser (part of the Smalltalk IDE) which automates certain low-level refactoring jobs, such as moving methods and instance variables up and down the class hierarchy,
- a rewrite tool which performs search and replace operations on syntactic entities, enabling more complex refactorings,
- and last but not least a unit test framework (I'm not sure whether this was developed in conjunction with the other tools) as unit testing is an important factor in ensuring that refactoring did not damage the semantics of the code.

Modern IDEs often have similar tools, but of course these are only applicable to supported languages. I'm not sure whether there are proper tools to refactor COBOL, FORTRAN or PL/I code, so the use of older languages may be a limiting factor for the feasibility of refactoring.

Comment: This was actually the first thing which came into my mind when reading the question. Can't believe the question got formerly 3 answers, but all of them overlooked this, which is IMHO one of the most important constraints.

Comment: ... and there is more to say about tooling. An important "tool" is the language itself - for example, typesafety helps a lot. I once had to deal with a code base written with some old 4GL tool, where the whole code base was stored in some binary BLOB. This made it almost impossible to "diff" any changes in version control, which makes refactoring inherently harder.

Comment: ... our solution was finally not to refactor - we replaced the 4GL code by a number of C# modules, it was one of the rare occasions where I favored a rewrite over  refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

> I've found that many codebases in large companies degrade over time

No, I find what degrades is (a) the existence of staff who understand the code, and (b) the correspondence between the understanding which staff have of the situation, and the concepts encoded in the structure and naming scheme of the source code.

> What differentiates a codebase that can be refactored, from one that cannot be feasibly refactored?

A codebase that can be refactored is one where staff are retained who are still fully in control of the code, in that they continue to possess a strong understanding of the code, the business purposes for which it was written, a strong understanding of exactly how the existing code lacks quality, the implications of proposed changes and refactorings, and the resources to execute such changes.

A codebase that cannot be refactored may lack any of these ingredients.

In the same way that a lot of rocket engineering from the 1960s is now lost to our understanding, often codebases reach a point where so much understanding has been lost that it makes more sense to start again on producing source code, than to try and adapt what already exists.

Many codebases are prematurely damaged by two things.

One is relentless development and accumulation of complexity in the source code to fulfil too many minor or auxiliary functions, to the extent that the development team cannot remain in control, and cannot continue over time to adapt the source code to serve its major and fundamental functions. This leads either to increasingly slowed development times approaching sclerosis, which stop the software being re-adapted as quickly as would be desirable, or it leads to changes being hacked in which then permanently destroy correctness or which grossly exacerbate the complexity of further change.

The other is the rapid loss of development staff responsible for the creation of source code and who have the most complete understanding of it. Second (or further) rounds of staff are introduced to work on the codebase who have had little or no contact with or supervision from the original creators, and this leads to rapid collapse both of the capability of the staff and of the coherence of the concepts embedded into the source code.

Both cancers can be related, in that excessive complexity makes it difficult to recruit further staff and reproduce the necessary understanding for them to work effectively on the source code, and failure to retain staff who are properly in control often leads to proliferative complexity in the source code which nobody properly understands (not even the creator).

It's why "pressure from above" is often so destructive for software development, because it often leads either to turnover as developers reject unreasonable additional stress, or it leads to modifications of source code that may meet short-term objectives, but which undermines the ability of the staff to maintain a controlling understanding of the source code, and therefore rapidly erodes the ability of the staff to adapt the source code further.

Comment: I do not agree with this answer as written. I think it merits more explanation as to how code does not degrade over time. To use a simple, but clear example, if I wrote something for flash 20 years ago, that code is clearly less efficient relative to modern techniques today. Same with things like Python. If I wrote something in Python 2, Python 3 offers better readability, more intuitive libraries, and better speeds for the same code I write a long time ago in Python 2. Moreover, project goals often change over time rendering decisions that originally mad sense, less effective realatively.

Comment: @GrantCurell, I fail to see how the comparative lower efficiency of older technologies, amounts to a "degradation" of the code itself. The gist of my answer anyway is not about how tools and technologies change over time, but about how, much sooner than that, the organisation loses the facility of having staff who actually comprehend what the code means and who retain enough understanding of how the codebase corresponds to the business operation that they can continue to re-adapt the code to suit that operation. It's this comprehension and understanding that tends to degrade, not the code.

Comment: Supporting @GrantCurell's point; the quote _"a lot of rocket engineering from the 1960s is now lost to our understanding"_ just goes to show how horribly unfounded this answer is. My best guess here is that this answer is built from a limited experience of how things worked at one or a handful of companies and has then wrongly been extrapolated to a blanket philosophy.

Comment: @Flater, I'm not quite sure what you disagree with about the rocket engineering analogy? It's widely accepted that many old designs of rocket technology are now completely defunct, because the manufacturing knowledge and craft techniques on which those designs relied has since been lost. Nowadays, rather than trying to adapt old designs (without understanding the constraints anymore), or rather than trying to recreate those craft understandings (when no knowledge remains), it makes more sense to simply begin the design process itself from scratch, and solve the problems in a modern context.

Comment: @Steve: I suspect you're referring to cases like the Apollo 11 telemetry data and engineering plans being lost. Yeah, data loss happens (physically and digitally), but that is not a driving factor as to defining technical debt. The techniques have not "been lost", but rather have **been let go**, i.e. a willful decision to not maintain something when a better approach was readily available. That's meaningfully different. Today's designs are different from the ground up _because the technology is different from the ground up_. Older designs are just generally not as good as newer ones.

Comment: @Flater, actually I was specifically thinking of the welding techniques on the F1 rocket engines. Nothing to do with lost data, but the loss of human understanding. Modern designs probably are better, the point is that all the effort that went into the old designs is now worthless, and the new designs have to be designed again from first principles (and those principles re-discovered). This is often what happens with rewrites of source code - developers have to start again in order to regain the understanding that the creators of the legacy code gained in the process of designing the original.

Comment: The rocketry analogy is interesting but needs explanation (or at least a link, since many might assume or argue that rocketry is no less advanced today); perhaps alluding to Damascus steel (or the pyramids?) would have been more orthodox (less opinionated/idiosyncratic). This answer makes some great points but gives axe grinding vibes (blaming managers, sensational "cancer" flourish). Also controversial advice to rewrite from scratch rather than refactor legacy code.

Comment: @benjimin, I only advise starting from scratch *when understanding has been lost* from the organisation, because what I'm arguing is that such understanding amongst the staff is central to their ability to continue supervising and correctly adapting the codebase.

Comment: @Steve: Starting from scratch is a last resort _when all else has failed_. This needs to be quantified by investing effort into everything that should precede ever being in such a scenario where rewriting is the last remaining option, because without it your answer is coming across as jumping to the rewrite conclusion way earlier than is reasonably justified. Is it a solution on an extreme end of the spectrum? Sure. But the extremity of that solution needs to be front and center for that advice to not be considered ill-advised to give.

Comment: @Steve: To put it more comically, yeah in an extreme survival situation you can resort to drinking your own urine to stave off dehydration. But if you offer it as a solution way to early or eagerly when there are still other options on the table, you're going to get pushback on that. Your answer is light on the preceding nuance that most people are going to expect/mandate before they will consider throwing the baby out with the bathwater in the way that you're mentioning it in this answer.

Comment: @Flater, if the staff have completely lost an understanding of the application, then that is a failure. There's lots of things businesses can do to stave off a catastrophic loss of the understanding which was used (or created) as part of the original application development, but once the loss actually occurs, you have to bootstrap again by following the development process back from a starting point at which no understanding exists. The source code isn't the baby. The comprehension that the development staff have of the application, is the real baby which demands so much time and effort.

Comment: @Steve: You're not really changing the specific bit that commenters have pointed out they disagree with. The source code is not just a discardable representation of the memory of the people that work on the project. When a person doesn't remember something, _they look at the source code_ to understand it again and refamiliarize themselves. They don't just blindly distrust the source code because they can't match it to their memories anymore. "I don't remember what in this bag, best throw it out and get a new bag" makes no sense. Just look in the damn bag.

Comment: One of the main issues with the approach that you're describing here is that developers who act like this often are the _source_ for managers becoming averse to suggestions of refactoring. The way you are currently describing throwing out the source code and starting anew is significantly too eager and when followed is going to cause significant rebuilding effort that could have been avoided by first investigating the existing source code instead of throwing it out. You're not incorrect that there are extreme cases, but you're way too quickly jumping to that extreme.

Comment: @Flater, you can draw some things back from the source code itself, but even relatively simple pieces of code with purely local effect, often fail to be self-explanatory to those not involved in their development. This is especially if the developer in question also hasn't developed something similar from scratch in the past. I'm not making an argument for the eager disposal of existing source code. I'm emphasising the importance of retaining an understanding, and emphasising the centrality of understanding as the main product of development time and effort, and... (1/3)

Comment: ...as the main precursor for successful production or re-adaptation of a codebase. Well-designed source code does speak to the reader, but it's not designed to be a free-standing training curriculum, capable of being interpreted without the presence of a single existing expert. There's no basis for thinking that the software development workforce can be reproduced by their reading of the source code produced by a previous generation - as if the average codebase contains a curriculum for a professional occupation and is an academic study into its own design. (2/3)

Comment: The *primary* way in which we produce the general professional capabilities of developers, and their understandings of a specific bespoke codebase, is by following the process associated with an initial development of software and the *writing* of source code. Despite the widespread wish that developers can be reproduced purely by *reading* source code (without someone to refer to and ask questions of, who is both a master developer and a professor on the particular codebase), there's no actual evidence that this is a particularly effective approach to reproduction. (3/3)

Comment: @Steve: (a) _"relatively simple pieces of code with purely local effect, often fail to be self-explanatory to those not involved in their development"_ That is not a universal constant and heavily relies on the cleanliness of the code (or lack thereof).  (b) "but it's not designed to be a free-standing training curriculum, capable of being interpreted without the presence of a single existing expert" That's interpreting the feedback you're getting here to the extreme end of the spectrum. The feedback is one of finer-grained nuance rather than a binary right/wrong. [..]

Comment: [..] The point being made here isn't that developers should solely rely on the source code for their understanding, the point is that the absence of understanding is not sufficient justification for "simply begin[ning] the design process itself from scratch" as you put it. It take a ludicrous amount of either knowledge extinction, technical debt, or lack of developer skill; before a developer gets to the stage where they cannot rely on a codebase + someone who can explain at least the business requirements (i.e. non-technical) and would benefit from just throwing it out and starting anew.

Comment: @Flater, there is no codebase of reasonable complexity, even the cleanest possible, where all features and functions are readable directly from the code. I'm certainly not adopting the binary position of "all source code is unreadable". And an expert who has acquired a relevant understanding in a different context, may find unfamiliar but good quality code which conforms broadly to their existing understanding, quite straightforward to interpret. What I am saying is that reading source code alone is not a major source of understanding for developers. (1/4)

Comment: Offhand there are at least two reasons for this. Firstly, source code simply doesn't encode much of the relevant information about the ingredients of its own design. It is the product of a design process, not a comprehensive description of how it was designed or what is (or isn't) accounted for in the design. This is why the Soviet reverse engineering approach to Western computer technology led to a collapse in their design capability. (2/4)

Comment: Secondly, source code often has to be structured in a single definitive way, such that certain functions, features, constraints, or patterns, are encoded a way that is local to a part of the codebase, while others end up encoded in a non-local way so that one conceptual feature has elements in seemingly disparate places (which nevertheless have to align or interact). Like spoor trails in the woods, they're not obvious if you're not yet even aware of the existence of the particular animal. (3/4)

Comment: Those are my points on reading source code. On "codebase + someone non-technical", I don't want to go on much longer, but I find the reality is that computerisation often leads to the eventual loss of non-technical people who understand anything pertinent. Old staff go, new staff come who know nothing of previous developments. The developers typically *are* the main reservoir of knowledge about what the business "requires" from its bespoke information systems and all aspects of why the design they have created takes a particular form. (4/4)

Comment: @Steve: There are just so many unrealistic points that you're introducing in justifying the proverbial gun you're trying to stick to, that it's no longer possible to productively add to this.

Comment: @Flater, I'm concerned myself about the length, but I'm surprised I'm encountering your resistance. The gun I'm sticking to is only that you need staff who understand the system in order to re-adapt it, and I've talked about the main ways in which that understanding is produced and reproduced. Crucially, I deny that *reading source code alone* is a main way of reproducing understanding - an experienced practitioner who reads code and infers something from it, is often applying far more understanding he already has from writing similar code himself, and gets back only a bit more from reading.

Comment: @Steve. And here we get to the crux: _"Crucially, I deny that reading source code alone is a main way of reproducing understanding"_ I never said that. My feedback was that your answer errs too far towards the extreme too early, so I called for nuance. You seem to have interpreted this as meaning that I wanted to err towards the other extreme end of the spectrum. This is not the case and was never a point I made, feel free to re-read anything I wrote _in its context_. It is impossible for me to distinguish a genuine misunderstanding from an intentional reductio ad extremis.

Comment: @Flater, I wasn't attributing those words to you, just restating my own position against what I think could be the underlying resistance. I welcome clarification between us, because I'm sure there is only misunderstanding. The point at which I'm saying rewrites become necessary is "when control and understanding has been lost". I've read all your previous comments again. You're obviously expressing concern about impulsive rewrites. But is it "too early", in your view, to rewrite when "control and understanding has been lost"? If that loss doesn't trigger a rewrite, then what later event does?

Answer (score 4):

There's this fact/urban legend that if you put a frog in hot water, it will jump out. But if you put a frog in cold water, it will stay in. If you then heat up the water, the frog does not notice and eventually gets boiled to death. This is most likely not true, but it serves as a fantastic analogy here.

Technical debt often behaves like this. If you introduce a developer to a codebase that's already steeped in technical debt, they will balk and either not want to take on the project or start it from the ground up. But any project, even ones that start cleanly, over time accrue technical debt, often stemming from small decisions that initially don't appear to have long term ramifications. This may even be statistically correct, but over time at least *some* of these decision have a bigger impact than expected and they become the precipitation points on which technical debt issues start to form.

> My question is: what conditions are sufficient for successful refactoring?

To continue the analogy, you're asking how the frog can make sure it doesn't get boiled to death once it's in the (now cool) pot.

First of all, it requires us to define what we consider to be too hot, and that's already a significant can of worms. So let's sidestep that discussion and conclude that we have some kind of metric in place, whether it's a specific temperature, a quick rise in temperature, ...

Next up, what good does that metric do if we don't give the frog the right tool to track it (thermometer, timer, ...). This means that you need to monitor the situation, such as:

- The velocity of the team over time. As the technical debt increases, you'll see that the devs need more and more time to deliver the same amount of features.
- Static analysis of the codebase, which can indicate a growing list of concerns/warnings.
- **Listening to your developers**. Often, technical debt is observed and communicated well before actual action is taken.

Okay, now we have a frog who knows the pot is heating up. But did we make sure that the frog jumped in a pot that it's actually capable of getting out of again?

The equivalent part to that analogy is having reliable (up to date) documentation of the business requirements and a testing suite (which ideally should be the code-equivalent of the requirements documentation). This enables you to refactor any part of your codebase while maintaining confidence that the refactoring isn't changing the actual behavior.

---

Really, all I've done here in this answer is list the main ingredients to create a dev team that does not let technical debt pile up:

- **Agree** on the definition of technical debt and good/bad practice
- **Observe** the current state of the technical debt and good/bad practice
- **Prepare** to have to fix the current state of the technical debt and good/bad practice

I can't spell the whole process out, because this is way too contextual for every company and situation. If there were a one-size-fits-all solution to this, it would already be a widely distributed guideline. As it currently stands, technical debt requires a balancing of business and technical needs and requires cooperation with the non-technical side of the company who are usually in control of the budgets and requirements, and that's not something you can prescribe in a guideline.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on where you are coming from. There is a good argument for "never refactor" if you just look at it on a time cost vs new feature benefit point of view.

The common arguments in favour of refactoring tend to be more abstract

1. Maintainability. If the code is constantly worked on and "up to date" then its going to quicker to add features/fix bugs
2. Skills up to date. If you keep refactoring to the latest framework, programming language etc then your devs are always working with cutting edge tech, are easier to hire

Answer (score -1):

My honest answer is that mostly what prevents refactoring is time, i.e. resource availability. Especially in small companies there simply aren't enough bodies to refactor old stuff, what matters is developing new stuff.

Comment: That's the usual excuse, and it is always wrong, since it suffers from the misconception that refactoring is mostly an activity which runs separately from feature development. Refactoring is something I do whenever I want to make a change to a code base, and the change is hard, because the code is not in good shape. Or, whenever I made a few changes to a method or class, which made it a little bit messier, and I don't want to leave this mess behind. Often, I switch between these activities multiple times a day, it is inherent part of any effective development work.

Comment: ... but when you think of refactoring as an activity which takes two weeks for the team of unproductivity, don't be astonished when your manager isn't excited about it. Sure, sometimes you need such kind of refacorings - but 95% of all refactoring activity should not be subject to any individual time planning apart from other development activities.